# Out of Disk space Dialog issue while extracting MSI from Setup.exe

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have created an installer using a Basic MSI project and I given option to the user to install into a different drive if the default install directory is OUT OF DISK SPACE.

Currently it displays the OUT OF DISK SPACE dialog and it lets the user change the path to where he wants to install, but again it directs the user back to OUT OF DISK SPACE dialog soon after he clicks next.

i am facing this problem while extracting "msi" from "setup.exe",by default it is taking 'C' drive "Temp" folder for extraction.Is it possible change extracting path to some other folder ?

please tell me how i can solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no reasonable way to prompt the user for another TEMP folder on another drive and expect the user to have a clue what you are really asking, let alone pick a proper folder.  There is a point where insisting on installing a program does more harm than good.  You reached it.  Don't fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There is always space required on the Windows drive, not just in the temp folder. Windows installer creates caches there, for example.